# xcode does not show dataWithContentsOfURL method of NSData. if try to use then shows error?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, nsdata

I am using Xcode and swift to capture some data into a `NSData` type of object. I'm wondering why Xcode does show the method `dataWithContentsOfURL`. But the Apple doc site has the method. My sample code is alike:

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io") //sample url
let weatherData = NSData.
```

So, if I try to manually add that method, it shows an error :(

Is it a bug of my xcode or something else? anybody faces ever this type of issue before?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to use the following line of code and it worked nicely:

```
let weatherData = NSData(contentsOfURL: baseURL!, options: nil, error: nil)
```

Actually, I followed one YouTube tutorial and I searched in app doc under Objectiv-C section and there is a method dataWithContentsOfURL. But when I moved to Swift section, it is not there. So that is the proper way to resolve this using Swift. :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this:

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io") //sample url
let weatherData = NSData(contentsOfURL: baseURL!)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let weatherData = NSData(contentsOfURL: baseURL!, options: nil, error: nil)
```